# Query wp posts where post title starts with specific letters

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not sure how to achieve this, but I want to display results on a page where the post title starts with specific letters and those posts are part of one category.

I am able to display them from the category that they are part of, but how to accomplish displaying where post_title starts with letter A.

```
<?php 
    $letters = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'T');
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1947, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $letters as $letter ){
        ?><div class="col-md-12"><?php echo $letter; ?><hr/></div> <?php

        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  ?>                     
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"> 
            <div class="items">
            <h2 class="box">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank" style="color:#588033 !important"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
             <p>
                <?php  echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 30, '...' ); ?>  
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Any help appreciated, it could be an easy task but I am new to WP.

Comment: Please check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
    $letters = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'T');
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1947, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $letters as $letter ){
        ?><div class="col-md-12"><?php echo $letter; ?><hr/></div> <?php

        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  

        $title = get_the_title($post);

        $firstCharacter = $title[0];

        if(!in_array($firstCharacter, $letters)) continue;


        ?>                     
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"> 
            <div class="items">
            <h2 class="box">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank" style="color:#588033 !important"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
             <p>
                <?php  echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 30, '...' ); ?>  
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```